# Android: How to match font with image document?

Tags: android, pattern-matching

I'm building an OCR. I have already binerized image. But I need to know how to match font with images. I have come to know about tesseract. But it is a built in tool. Actually I need to know what is behind algorithm for matching image text with a font in .ttf format. If tesseract is the only choice for android then would you please describe some steps for integrating with windows7 as I'm not clear from Gautam's Blog. If there is any other built in method for android that match image pattern with a .ttf file please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to train the tesseract-enginge to your font. There is an exhaustive tutorial on this topic on the projects website. You don't have to train tesseract on an android device, but you will have to deploy the training results to it.

Comment: Would please share the URL of the tutorial? A brief tutorial describing environment setup on windows7 will be best.Thanks

Comment: if I have trained data for my language then is it enough to just add trained data in asset folder?